# iPhone x Header right item has lot of padding/margin

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, ionic3, iphone-x

**Latest Update:**

I have found the issue. You can see that it has `90px` `padding-right` on `title-ios`. Do you know why?

[image]

**Original Quetion:**

**Android UI** - header is **Correct**

[image]

**iPhone X ios 11.1 UI** - Header is **Wrong**

[image]

*html*

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle icon-only outline color="light" class="border-none">
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      <ion-grid no-padding>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-6>
            <span class="font-size-18 font-family-trench" *ngIf="data==null">BUDGET MY RENO</span>
            <span class="font-size-18" *ngIf="data!=null">{{data.project}}</span>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-6>
            <ion-icon name="ios-add-outline" float-right tappable class="font-size-30" (click)="goToNewProject()" *ngIf="data==null"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon name="ios-create-outline" float-right tappable class="font-size-30 margin-top-minus-4" (click)="goToNewProject()"
              *ngIf="data!=null"></ion-icon>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

**Question:** As you can see I have constructed the right item (`+`) inside the `ionic grid`. Can you tell me why this much of right padding/margin on an `iOS` device? How can I sort out this issue?

***Runtime style code on iPhone x iOS 11.1:***

[image]

**Note:** Actually this is not only a issue on `iPhone x, 11.1` but also same for the `iPhone-6s-Plus, 9.0`. That means issue on my HTML code.Maybe grid which I have used.Any clue?

**Update:**

Even though it shows grid `width` as `100%`, on computed section it shows as `195px`. On `Android`, it shows as `324px`. Do you know why?

[image]

Comment: what is the width of `ion-title` in ios iphoneX?

Comment: you probably need to use `ion-buttons` with `end` attribute on the `+` button

Comment: I don't think where it'll work. Because I have a problem with parent element i.e. `title-ios`. The `+` icon is a way, inner child of it. `title-ios` has `90px` `padding-right`. I don't know how it came there? @SurajRao

Comment: I was talking about putting it after ion-title..

Comment: Yes, If we put something after the `ion-title` then that too inherited that alien `90px` padding no.If you see my latest update image then you'll see that. @SurajRao